# Product Publisher Application (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher)

Tags: eclipse, pde

I have an eclipse bundle with an application and product configuration file (myproduct.product). When I export the product I get executable that I can run just fine.

But how do I export this .product file from a java application? I have looked at the example at the bottom of this page:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher

but I don't see how its possible to specify the .product file as input. There are also some ant-scripts on the above link but it could be nice to keep the publish in pure java. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably miss something when you read the twiki page. It already has given a sample to demonstrate how to publish a product in command line. [Product Publisher](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher#Product_Publisher)

Note: the product publisher doesn't publish the features/plug-ins that constitute the product, so you have to call FeatureBundle publisher to export features and plug-ins.

Comment: Yeah as I understand the "Features And Bundles Publisher Application" should be run followed by the "Product Publisher". But I still need to setup a PDEBuild job to make sure everything is specified correctly.

Comment: @tul, you're right. Publisher just exports the building result to p2 repository or release. You must build your projects firstly whatever using PDE build or others. The same process of exporting your product in GUI, PDE also build the projects firstly, then calls publisher to generate repository.